# Update Packages.json automatically with the pre-installed moduels in NODEJS

Tags: node.js, npm

In my local machine, I worked on a node.js app, I had installed many packages before initializing the package.json.

When I initialized the Package.json using:

`npm init`

I got the package.json but it does not contain all the dependencies that exist in the node_modules,

Which caused me a problem of missing packages when I moved to the production server (I run npm install)

Is there a way to automatically include all of them in the dependencies part.

Here is the JSON file I have:

```js
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "xxxxxxx",
  "main": "server.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "date-utils": "^1.2.21",
    "mssql": "^4.0.4",
    "mysql": "^2.11.1",
    "seriate": "^0.9.0",
    "websocket": "^1.0.23",
    "winston": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://gitlab.com/odot-web/hefner-socket.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nodejs",
    "hefner",
    "socket"
  ],
  "author": "xxxx",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://gitlab.com/odot-web/hefner-socket/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://gitlab.com/odot-web/hefner-socket#README"
}
```

Comment: um, `npm install`? Not totally sure what you're asking

Comment: are you sure that there are more packages at `./node_modules`. As you said that you had installed many packages before `npm init`, they could ended up being installed on parent folders.

Comment: @scniro I tried npm install, it only installed packages in the dependencies part of the packages.json,

Comment: In my local machine, I have for example a package called debug, this package is not included in the package.json, 
So when I moved to the production server, and run npm install it did not install 'debug' package, and I got an error when I run the script of:

Error: Cannot find module 'debug'

Comment: you need to add it to the package.json file. e.g. `npm install debug --save` will install the package _and_ save it to the package.json file

Comment: @scniro 'npm install debug --save' will install the package and add it to the package.json, but this way I had to isntall them one by one, they are a lot, is there any automatic way to update the packages.json at once from the development server